# Roots to an equation, $\frac{3-2x}{x-1}-\sqrt[4]{x^3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, roots, radicals

> Find the number of roots to $\frac{3-2x}{x-1}-\sqrt[4]{x^3}=0$.

My method:

$\frac{3-2x}{x-1}-\sqrt[4]{x}$, we multiply $\sqrt[4]{x}$ and $x-1$ to both sides, getting $3\sqrt[4]{x}-2x\sqrt[4]{x}-x(x-1)=0$.  We let $\sqrt[4]{x}=k$.  Then we have $3k-2xk-x^2+x=0$.  Finding the discriminant ($b^2-4ac$), getting $4k^2+8k+1$, evidently greater than $0$, which means there are 2 roots.

Plotting this on Desmos gives 1 root only. How am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your analysis is wrong becase $k$ depends on $x$: $k=\sqrt[4]x$. Instead, write $x=k^4$:
$$3k-2k^5-k^8+k^4=0$$
$$k^8+2k^5-k^4-3k=0$$
Descartes's rule of signs tells us there is exactly one positive root for this last polynomial. $k$ cannot be negative as it is the fourth root of $x$, so the lone root of the polynomial in $k$ translates to only one root for the original equation.

Comment: sorry, I do not seem to understand how your method is different

Comment: @XcoderX Only mine explains why your method is wrong, which is what you wanted, right?

Comment: Yes.  But the k=quad root x part and x equal k^4 part seems unclear to me

Comment: @XcoderX _Because_ $k=\sqrt[4]x$, we can take the fourth power of both sides to get $k^4=x$. (This is not always correct, but if $k$ is positive like it is here it is OK.)

Comment: Wait, it is okay?  You mean my solution?

Comment: @XcoderX It starts out OK, but when you get to $3k-2xk-x^2+x=0$ you need to switch tracks to mine.

Comment: Ah okay thanks, understand now.

Answer (score 0):

write your equation in the form
$$(3-2x)=(x-1)\sqrt[4]{x^3}(x-1)$$ for $x\ne 1$ and raise to the power four:
$$(3-2x)^4=x^3(x-1)^4$$
then you have to solve the equation
$$-{x}^{7}+4\,{x}^{6}-6\,{x}^{5}+20\,{x}^{4}-97\,{x}^{3}+216\,{x}^{2}-
216\,x+81
=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=t^4$, where $t>0$.

Thus, $$t^7+2t^4-t^3-3=0$$ and we see that there is one changing of coefficients sing.

Thus, the polynomial $t^7+2t^4-t^3-3$ has one positive root by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs

In your reasoning you need to remember that $k\geq0,$ which gives that your method does not work.

Comment: well, do you know why my method is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Since $k$ is a function of $x$, the coefficients of your quadratric equation are functions of $x$.

The quadratic formula is useless in that context, since that would be solving for $x$ in terms of $x$.

Here's how I would approach the problem . . .

Let $f(x)={\displaystyle{{\small{\frac{3-2x}{x-1}}}-\sqrt[4]{x^3}}}$.

You want to count the number of real zeros of $f$.

Rather than trying to solve the equation $f(x) = 0$, instead, analyze the behavior of $f$.

The domain of $f$ is $[0,1)\cup(1,\infty)$.

On the interval $[0,1)$, we have
$$\frac{3-2x}{x-1}<0$$
$$-\sqrt[4]{x^3} \le 0$$
hence $f(x) < 0$.

Thus, $f$ has no real zeros in the interval $[0,1)$.

On the interval $(1,\infty)$, the functions
$$\frac{3-2x}{x-1}$$
$$-\sqrt[4]{x^3}$$
are both strictly decreasing, hence $f$ is strictly decreasing.

It follows that $f$ has at most one real root.

Letting $x$ approach $1$ from the right, we get
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to 1^{+}} f(x)
&=\;\lim_{x\to 1^{+}} \frac{3-2x}{x-1}-\sqrt[4]{x^3}\\[4pt]
&=\;\lim_{x\to 1^{+}} \frac{3-2x}{x-1}-\lim_{x\to 1^{+}}\sqrt[4]{x^3}\\[4pt]
&=\;\infty-1\\[4pt]
&=\;\infty\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Letting $x$ approach $\infty$, we get
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)
&=\;\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{3-2x}{x-1}-\sqrt[4]{x^3}\\[4pt]
&=\;\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{3-2x}{x-1}-\lim_{x\to \infty}\sqrt[4]{x^3}\\[4pt]
&=\;-2-\infty\\[4pt]
&=\;-\infty\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Since $f$ is continuous on $(1,\infty)$, it follows that $f$ has at least one real root.

Therefore $f$ has exactly one real root.